# StaleObjectStateException when try to add @Version in JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, version

I try to use hibernate envers in my project for versioning.
Used jpa, jpa repository, spring and hibernate as provider.

There is jpa entity

```
@Entity
@Audited
@IdClass(CusomerId.class)
@Table(name = "Cusomer", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name", "surname", "org" })})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "org", length = 100, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String org;

    @Column(name = "metaInfo", length = 100, unique = false, nullable = true)
    private String metaInfo;

    public Customer(String name, String surname, String org, String metaInfo) {
        this.name=name;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.org=org;
        this.metaInfo=metaInfo;
    }
}
```

In application I use Jpa Repository, so, my repository looks like

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, CutomerId>{}
```

In my flow,

```
Customer customer1 = new Customer("aaa", "bbb", "23", "this is secret info1")
Customer customer2 = new Customer("aaa", "bbb", "23", "this is secret info2 updated")
Customer customer3 = new Customer("aaa", "bbb", "23", "this is secret info3")
```

I just call

```
customerRepository.save(customer1); 
customerRepository.save(customer2);
customerRepository.save(customer3);
```

Code works ok and in base I have updated entity. But if I add to my entity `@Version` version; table, there is `StaleObjectStateException` when I try to save customer3.

I expect, that this issue linked with save method in `SimpleJpaRepository`. If entity is exists, it try to merge new entity with entity with same  key.

P.S. I have w.a. gor this issue, but I belive that exists correct way to resolve this issue. Instead of `save` and `merge` other times of entity, I in first time write in base, in other times I read from base and update entity by hand

```
public void add(String name, String surname, String age,
                    String metaInfo) {
        Customer customer = CustomerRepository.findRiskBustomerByNameAndSurnameAndAge(
                name, surname, age);

        if (customer == null) {
            customer = new Customer(name, surname,
                    age, metaInfo);

            customerRepository.save(customer);
        } else {
            customer.setMetaInfo(metaInfo);

        }
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Comment: You should at least implement `hashCode` and `equals` in a proper way else there is no way for hibernate to detect the presence of an entity. The same for your `CusomerId` class.

Comment: Also the `save` method checks if the entity exists in the current EntityManager it doesn't check if it exists in the database!.

Comment: @M.Deinum version filed must used in hashCode and equals?

Comment: no it shouldn't. Nor the `metaInfo`.

Comment: @M.Deinum overrided hashCode and equals not helped(same error-message). About EntityManager, may be I need to do any flush operations after I save entity?

Comment: You must do the same for the `CustomerId` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum this way doesn't work

Comment: Actually it does work and does exactly what it should do, after looking at it again. You save the first `Customer` which gets a version. Then you save the second one which doesn't have a version. Hence hibernate fails stating that the entity you try to save is stale as a newer version is in the database. So basically it works as it should.